# replaceAll method regex

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

My sample input is  `"0X10001,0X10002,0X610001,0X610002"`

```
System.out.println(st.replaceAll(regex, "0"));
```

My output should be  `"010001,010002,610001,610002"`
`0X` should be replaced by
`0` --> if length is 7
`""`-->  if length is 8

what is the regex I have to use?
`([0X]){1,2}` not getting desired output by this.

Comment: Post the regex that you already have and that you want to improve upon.

Comment: ([0X]){1,2} not getting desired output by this.

Comment: do two separate replaces: First one replace `0X(\d{5})` to `0$1`, second one replace `0X(\d{6})` to `$1`

Comment: @AdrianShum You'll want to switch the order and/or check for word boundaries.

Comment: @Adrian Shum thank you, when I use two replaces like this  System.out.println(st.replaceAll("0X(\\d{5})", "0$1").replaceAll("0X(\d{6})", "$1"));  it is showing error (saying I should use \b,\n...…) in eclipse

Comment: @shmoesel: yes I was intentionally not giving the full regex, but just giving basic idea (and was expecting OP to write his own)

Comment: You need to escape backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
String st = "0X10001,0X10002,0X610001,0X610002";
System.out.println(st.replaceAll("0X(?=\\d{6})|(0)X(?=\\d{5})", "$1"));
```

*Output*

`010001,010002,610001,610002`

*Explanation*

As the regex engine scans, the pattern `|` will always try left side before right side, so as it advances, it will first it try `0X(?=\\d{6})`, which is a match for `0X` followed by 6 digits (using zero-width positive look-ahead). If that matches, nothing is captured, so `$1` is empty, and `0X` is replaced by empty string.

If that didn't match, it tries `(0)X(?=\\d{5})`, i.e. match `0X` followed by 5 digits. If that matches, the `0` is captured in group 1, so `$1` is `0`, and `0X` is replaced by `0`.

If neither match, the regex engine will try again at the next position in the input string.

Comment: tricky but interesting :)

Comment: thank you for the explanation and answer @Andreas

Answer (score -2):

`replaceAll("0X(?=\\d{6})|(0)X(?=\\d{5})", "$1")`
works fine for the given issues